# looping a mathematic equation

Tags: java, equation

so i'm trying to make a cashier like program that keep add up depend on how much the user buy the product, but my program wont add the value but it keep replacing it

Class:

```
public class Class {
    private double drink, pdrink;
                public void SetDrink (double drink)
                {
                    this.drink = drink;
                }
                public void SetPDrink (double pdrink)
                {
                    this.pdrink = pdrink;
                }

            public double getDrink()
            {
                if (drink==1)
                    drink=500;
                else if (drink==2)
                    drink=1000;
                else if (drink==3)
                    drink=3000;
                else
                    drink=0;


                return drink;
            }


    public double getPDrink()
            {
    double total = getDrink();
            return total;
        }
}
```

Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch = 0;
            char mi = 0;

    Scanner Class = new Scanner (System.in);
    Class p = new Class();
            int choice;
            char repeat = 'y';
            char drink = 'y' ;


            do {
    System.out.println("do you want to buy drinks?");
    System.out.println("1. A (500)");
    System.out.println("2. B (1000)");
    System.out.println("3. C (1500)");
    System.out.println("0 to not choose");
    System.out.println("Please choose you drink");

    p.SetDrink(Class.nextDouble());

    System.out.println("do you want to buy more?");

    mi = Class.next().charAt(0);

} while (mi == 'y');
    System.out.println("total= "+p.getDrink());
}
    }
```

i'm thinking about using "do while" but i'm not really sure how to do that

Edit: i'm using oop, i'm trying to use switch on class but it didnt work

Comment: Maybe the class that `p` belongs to needs an `addToDrinks` method, instead of `setDrink`.

Comment: Your snippet won't compile. `class.nextDouble` and `Class.next` are both invalid. Do you mean something like scanner?

Comment: yes its scanner, i'm using oop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am using Scanner, you can use any other library to read input from console. Not fixed your business logic like printing "total" value.

```
    char mi;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double total = 0.0;
    do {
        System.out.println("do you want to buy drinks?");
        System.out.println("1. A (500)");
        System.out.println("2. B (1000)");
        System.out.println("3. C (1500)");
        System.out.println("0 to not choose");
        System.out.println("Please choose you drink");
        //p.SetDrink(sc.nextDouble()); // not working unknown p in OP, so commented
        char drink = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(drink); // just printing user's choice for drink
        switch (drink) {
                case 'A':
                    total += 500;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    total += 1000;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    total += 1500;
                    break;
                default:
                    total += 0;
            }

        System.out.println("do you want to buy more?");

        mi = sc.next().charAt(0);
    } while (mi=='y');
    System.out.println("total : " + total);
```

output:

> ```
> do you want to buy drinks?
> 1. A (500)
> 2. B (1000)
> 3. C (1500)
> 0 to not choose
> Please choose you drink
> C
> C
> do you want to buy more?
> y
> do you want to buy drinks?
> 1. A (500)
> 2. B (1000)
> 3. C (1500)
> 0 to not choose
> Please choose you drink
> A
> A
> do you want to buy more?
> n
> total : 2000.0
> ```

Comment: my problem is i want to make when people choose A, then it would store the 500, then if they say want more and chose B it would be A+B and printed out in the total

Comment: @Arvezia updated code as per your OP.

Comment: thank you, this is not really what I need since I need to use this on OOP and I don't know how to use this on it, but at least it does the job when I don't use OOP

Comment: Please add complete code if you want in terms of OOP, in OP it was not clear what `p` stands for so is `p.SetDrink` and `p.getDrink`?

Comment: yes, im sorry this is the first time i use this kind of site so i dont really know what should i put